# Favicon works fine on localhost but problems on server (with Typo3)

Tags: html, image, typo3, favicon

I created several sizes of the favicon, putting 16,24,32 and 128px versions all together in the favicon.ico file. This works pretty fine on my localhost but as soon as we use the same files and code on the production server using Typo3, the favicon is really pixelated in firefox and doesn't show up at all in IE9.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably a cache issue if it works on some browsers, and just use the 32px favicon on it's own, there is no need for a bigger size as it's only a small image for a tab.

try a hard refresh or manually clearing your cache in the browser options.

Comment: it actually was a cache problem that took 24 hours to update. not inside firefox but all the system through. BUT: there is a need of serveral sizes (opera, apple, 24px for ie9 tapped and so on)

Answer (score 0):

the question is where is your favicon located,in which way did u put it in Typo3???

U should check your paths, cause if u have it inside HTML u have to correct path to it with starting from "Fileadmin/.." as well as if u have it inside yout Template TS Setup.

This is how i link to favicons and works with no problem.

```
page.shortcutIcon = fileadmin/img/favicon.png
```

It is placed in template TS setup before:

```
page.10 = TEMPLATE
```

And other way is by using this code:

```
page.headerData {
  5 = HTML
  5.value = XXX   // here goes any meta, link etc. tag for header part
  10 = HTML
  10.value = XXX   // here goes any meta, link etc. tag for header part,
  etc.
}
```

As for favicon sizes, 32px is just enought as Samayres said.